# Lint fixing during build process

Tags: javascript, angular, build, lint

I have a angular project that has some linting configured.

Currently whenever there are linting errors the build fails.
What my colleague suggested was to fix linting errors during the build process.

*Is it okay to do so?*

Few issues I can think of:

- The lint fixes would be required to be committed and pushed during the build (extra config, etc.)
- There may be lint fixes that may break the code
- There will still be errors that can't be auto fixed like requiring a prefix in naming components etc.

Is linting during the build recommended because I can't find projects that do that.

I believe linting are for similar code structure and similar practices in a project, What's the point if the team don't follow those rules.
We will be going to add linting fix during build if I don't have strong points to hold.

Comment: This is actually a never ending and huge discussion, but you already listed some of the negative side effects on such automated linting. There surely are tools out there doing exactly this but it is not recommended.
The problem seems to be within your team.

Comment: I believe linting is always good practice as it holds the team to specific standards and removes inconsistencies especially when working with a team. Using Lint fixes, the team members are "forced" to work with a standard. In regards to your build issue, personally I "lint" the code before building with specified linting commands before building, and manually fix any issues that don't fix themselves. This also teaches you to stick to the standard.

Comment: @ArpanKc are those auto lint fixes you do yourself (as personal practice and also across team) or are those part of build, as I want lint fixes out of the build as this breaks team to follow a practice.

Comment: They should definitely always be out of the build, It should be part of your personal dev environment. Making it part of an automated build process will definitely cause issues.